# Is there any good site for downloading flash presentation template?

Tags: flash, templates

I am looking for a base to work on a presentation. I am using flash cs4. I know little of actionscript only so i just wondered if there are any template where i can just manage my content to make the presentation instead of coding from scratch. Is there any good site for downloading free flash presentation template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some time back i created flash presentation from prezi.com. You can also search existing presentations for templates. But it doesn't provide any coding facility. You might would like to try it out.

Comment: yes, you can download your presentation in Flash format on desktop .